# How to represent temporal relation like <time:before> in RDF?

Tags: sequence, rdf, temporal

I have a problem for RDF data representation. The table contains millions of rows and several thousands of `subject_id`s. Here is a sample of table.

```
row_id      subject_id    DateTime
34951953    144           14/07/2016 22:00
34952051    145           14/07/2016 22:00
34951954    146           14/07/2016 22:00    
34951976    144           15/07/2016 3:00
34952105    146           15/07/2016 3:00
34952004    144           15/07/2016 20:00
```

I have done simple 1:1 rdf mapping conversion like this using jena.

```
<foo/data/row_id=34951953>  <foo/data/subject_id>   "144"
<foo/data/row_id=34951954>  <foo/data/subject_id>   "146"
<foo/data/row_id=34951954>  <foo/data/subject_id>   "146"
<foo/data/row_id=34952051>  <foo/data/subject_id>   "145"
<foo/data/row_id=34951976>  <foo/data/subject_id>   "144"
<foo/data/row_id=34952105>  <foo/data/subject_id>   "146"
<foo/data/row_id=34952004>  <foo/data/subject_id>   "144"
<foo/data/row_id=34951953>  <foo/data/DateTime> "14/07/2016 22:00:00"
<foo/data/row_id=34952051>  <foo/data/DateTime> "14/07/2016 22:00:00"
<foo/data/row_id=34952054>  <foo/data/DateTime> "14/07/2016 22:00:00"
<foo/data/row_id=34951976>  <foo/data/DateTime> "15/07/2016 3:00:00"
<foo/data/row_id=34952105>  <foo/data/DateTime> "15/07/2016 3:00:00"
<foo/data/row_id=34952004>  <foo/data/DateTime> "15/07/2016 20:00:00"
```

Now, I want to add some temporal attributes like `<time:before>` for all the `subject_id`, i.e., for sequential information. Here are examples of what I want:

**For subject_id = 144;**

```
<foo/data/row_id=34951953> <time:before> <foo/data/row_id=34951976>
<foo/data/row_id=34951976> <time:before> <foo/data/row_id=34952004>
```

**for subject_id = 146;**

```
<foo/data/row_id=34951954> <time:before> <foo/data/row_id=34952105>
```

Can I explicitly add temporal relation, `<time:before>`? Is there any better way to solve this kind of issue?

Comment: I would suggest you start by changing the datetime values to standard form (a la `2016-07-15T22:00:00`), and store them as such (i.e., as `xsd:datetime`, rather than `xsd:string`). This lets you easily do things like `ORDER BY` in older-to-newer or newer-to-older, among other things...

Comment: You might also look to Ian Davis' blog series on [Representing Time in RDF](http://blog.iandavis.com/2009/08/representing-time-in-rdf-part-1/) ... As you can see there, this is _not_ a simple question.

Comment: Thank you @TallTed for valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What**

Obviously, you can use [`rdf:Seq`](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_seq) or [`rdf:List`](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_list). However, querying these structures is [painful](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2014/04/rdf-lists-and-sparql.html).

I suggest you to find appropriate ontology or vocabulary for this kind of time series, or to use your own lightweight vocabulary. Please note that `time:` prefix is reserved by the [Time ontology](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-owl-time-20170606/).

Let us assume that you use property named `foo:before`.

**How**

You can add triples with this property in your RDF data using SPARQL:

```
INSERT
{
?row_1 foo:before ?row_2 .
}
WHERE {
    ?row_1  foo:subject ?subject .
    ?row_2  foo:subject ?subject .
    ?row_1  foo:time ?time_1 .
    ?row_2  foo:time ?time_2 .
    FILTER (?time_1 > ?time_2)
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?row_3  foo:subject ?subject .
        ?row_3  foo:time ?time_3 .
        FILTER ((?time_1 < ?time_3) && (?time_3 < ?time_2))
    }
}
```

**Performance**

[Analogous](http://jena.linkeddata.fssprus.ru/dataset.html?tab=query&ds=/default#query=PREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0Aprefix+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0Aprefix+org%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Forg%23%3E%0Aprefix+wd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0Aprefix+wdt%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT+%3Fosp+%3Fname1+%3Fname2%0AWHERE+%7B%0A++%3Fr1+org%3AmemberOf+%3Fosp+%3B%0A++++++foaf%3Aname+%3Fname1+.%0A++%3Fr2+org%3AmemberOf+%3Fosp+%3B%0A++++++foaf%3Aname+%3Fname2+.%0A++FILTER+(%3Fname1+%3C+%3Fname2)%0A++FILTER+NOT+EXISTS+%7B+%3Fr3+org%3AmemberOf+%3Fosp++%3B+foaf%3Aname+%3Fname3+.+FILTER+((%3Fname1+%3C+%3Fname3)+%26%26+(%3Fname3+%3C+%3Fname2)+)+%7D%0A%7D+LIMIT+100)  query performs about 1 minute on my endpoint with 3000+ "subjects" and 60000+ "rows".

Probably your CSV table was exported from RDBMS, where you have all these data normalized.  Then you could create SQL view with neighboring pairs of "rows" and export it or generate RDF triples using [R2RML](https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/) tools.

Another option is to sort/transform RDF file in some way and generate triples that you need with `sed`, `python` etc.

**Update**

Of course, your dates should be of type `xsd:dateTime`, or at least should be comparable in a natural way.

Comment: Thank you @Stanislav for prompt response. Appreciated.

Comment: _"Please note that time: prefix is reserved by the Time ontology"_ - Reserved? How? Where? Is there a registry?

Comment: @MichałPolitowski, probably another word (not 'reserved') would be more suitable. This prefix is well-known, see [here](https://prefix.cc/time) (or rather [this](http://prefix.cc/popular/all.file.json) file). A reader might be confused, if somebody uses `time:` for something else.

Comment: Also, "The suggested prefix for the OWL-Time namespace is time[:]"  — from https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-time/#abstract